# How to set up multiple client under the same address?

Tags: shared-wallet

I want to use my all my computer to run Bitcoins, but is it possible to have it the same address so it generate under one wallet?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "run Bitcoins"? Do you mean mine them? If so, just run one client and run as many miners as you want using that same client.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the private key from one and import it into the others